# Run C++ on MacOS without xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I don't have Xcode installed on my Mac OS 13.6 but I would like to run c++ on vs code. Is there a way to do that without the need for Xcode to be installed? Also, can I run an older version of Xcode and run c++ without problems?

Note: Would be great if someone posted a link for a tutorial.

Comment: You could install a C++ compiler such as gcc: `brew install gcc` should install it (it might take a while!). With it you will be able to compile C++ programs.

Comment: Unfortunately, homebrew isn't supported anymore on my mac version

Comment: What do you have against XCode?

Comment: @molbdnilo Nothing, I just don't know how to use it properly, maybe due to my old macos version.

Comment: You don't need to use the IDE, you can install the command line toools and use whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may download and install [LLVM 13.0.1](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-13.0.1) for Darwin or a small part of Xcode, Xcode command line tools: [`xcode-select --install`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/).

Both will result in installing clang++.

Comment: It through out that error:
error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: I would strongly recommend going with the second options (Xcode cmdline-utils) because you most probably will need some of the other utilities as well(with or without c++!).

Comment: @OmarOshiba what happens when you type in `clang++ -v`?

Comment: @NikitaDemodov This causes an error:
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.

Comment: Have you followed the tutorial? What does `xcode-select -p` show? If not `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, then try `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: But what exactly was the problem and how is it fixed?

Comment: Mess of older version artifacts.

Comment: So basically I am just using the command line tools only, but not Xcode. Am I right?

Comment: yes, you are correct